# Why won't this jQuery Execute in IE6

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6

I have a js file that is being called in the body. The jQuery won't execute in IE6, IE8 and possibly IE7. Here's the files contents:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('img[src="/v/vspfiles/templates/cyberfront/images/buttons/btn_addtocart_small.gif"]').replaceWith('<br /><span id="blackbutton" class="mediumbutton" style="display:block;">Add to Cart</span>');
$('input[src="/v/vspfiles/templates/cyberfront/images/buttons/btn_go_gray.gif"]').replaceWith('<input type="submit" class="graybutton smallbutton" name="Go" alt="Go" value="Go" title="Go">');
$('input.previous_page_img').attr({class: 'graybutton mediumbutton', src: '/v/vspfiles/templates/eastcoasttvs/images/buttons/btn_prevpage.png'});
$('input.next_page_img').attr({class: 'graybutton mediumbutton', src: '/v/vspfiles/templates/eastcoasttvs/images/buttons/btn_nextpage.png'});
$('img[src="/v/vspfiles/templates/cyberfront/images/Bullet_MoreInfo.gif"]').replaceWith('<span class="learnmore">Learn More</span>');
$('td[background="/v/vspfiles/templates/cyberfront/images/Divider_Horizontal.gif"]').remove();
$('td.v65-productRow-bottom').remove();
$('select').wrap('<div class="styled-select" />');
});
```

Should I put this in the head rather than a separate file? Should I call the file in the head.  Is there a problem with my markup?

***----EDIT----***

I made a fiddle and tested it in IE6, IE7 & IE8 I've confirmed it does not work in those browsers. The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2mJWF/

If it renders properly this will be the final result

```
<body>
<br><span id="blackbutton" class="mediumbutton" style="display:block;">Add to Cart</span>
<input type="submit" class="graybutton smallbutton" name="Go" alt="Go" value="Go" title="Go">
<input type="image" src="/v/vspfiles/templates/eastcoasttvs/images/buttons/btn_prevpage.png" class="graybutton mediumbutton">
<input type="image" src="/v/vspfiles/templates/eastcoasttvs/images/buttons/btn_nextpage.png"     class="graybutton mediumbutton">
<span class="learnmore">Learn More</span>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div class="styled-select"><select>
<option>Hello</option>
</select></div>
</body>
```

The easiest way to tell if it worked is to see if you see a line that says Hllo Hello if you don't see that line, it worked, if you do see the line it did not.

Comment: Yikes. That's a block of selectors.

Comment: @JaredFarrish My software is engineered poorly... You should see my other file

Comment: Is IE giving you any errors or is it just "failing", if so *how* is it failing? Regardless, though, putting this in the `<head>` rather than `<body>` or inline vs. in a file won't make any difference.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall It's just not working...

Comment: Which part isn't working? Is there some sample HTML to go along with that jQuery?

Comment: @muistooshort I made a fiddle. The whole entire script does not work http://jsfiddle.net/2mJWF/

Comment: In your JS Fiddle, what report does the JS Lint button give you? Any errors or problems?

Comment: I don't have IE handy but AFAIK `.attr('class', ...)` is a bit dodgy in IE. Comment it all out and uncomment one by one until it breaks.

Comment: @muistooshort @David-Thomas it says something about class, I've decided to switch to `.addClass` http://jsfiddle.net/2mJWF/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking the JSLint on that fiddle, I found out setting the class attribute is not valid so I changed it to `.addClass`. My updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2mJWF/4/.

Answer (score 0):

You've got object literals with `class` as an unquoted property name. IE may not like that given that `class` is a reserved ([for future use](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words#Words_reserved_for_possible_future_use)) word in JavaScript. Trying putting it in quotes (single or double is fine):

```
// instead of
{class : "something"}
// try
{"class" : "something"}


...
$('input.previous_page_img').attr({"class": 'graybutton mediumbutton', src: '/v/vspfiles/templates/eastcoasttvs/images/buttons/btn_prevpage.png'});

$('input.next_page_img').attr({"class": 'graybutton mediumbutton', src: '/v/vspfiles/templates/eastcoasttvs/images/buttons/btn_nextpage.png'});
...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2mJWF/3/

Comment: Please add your code to the answer. What if JSFiddle goes down?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker - Done. (Though really my introductory paragraph was all the information needed and I wouldn't have bothered with the JSFiddle if the OP hadn't included one for me to update.)

Comment: P.S. When I tried the original JSFiddle in IE7 I saw the "Hllo Hello" that apparently indicates it isn't working. After adding quotes as per my answer and updated fiddle I no longer see "Hllo Hello" so I assume that means it works.